# How can I detect whether a directory is writeable in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, permissions, directory, writable

I am using Ruby and need to detect whether a directory is writeable before trying to create new files.

I have tried the following code, which correctly returns true/false depending on whether @path is a directory.
However, it still returns true when there is no write permission to the @path folder.

```
  if File.directory?(@path) && File.writable?(@path)
    #is a writeable directory
    true
  else
    #is not a writeable directory
    false
  end
```

I have looked at the help for the File and Dir classes and cannot see any method that allows me to check directory write permissions. Is there a way?

I only need it work on Windows, using Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows you want the [`File.attributes`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/win32-file/0.6.7/File#attributes-class_method) or [`File.readonly?`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/win32-file/0.6.7/File#readonly%3F-class_method) methods from the [win32-file](http://rubygems.org/gems/win32-file) gem.

*And you should consider contributing to Daniel Berger, as without his win32- gems  Ruby on Windows would be a far more hostile place.*

Comment: It seems that File.attributes will only return `["directory", "indexed"]` for a directory where write permission has been denied.
Similarly, File.readonly? returns false.

When used on a file, both the #attributes and #readonly? methods work as expected.

Comment: @SimonMayer Very odd. I've never used this, and I'm not on Windows now to test, but my experience is that the win32- gems are very reliable. Since this is documented explicitly as applying to directories as well, I wonder: are you _sure_ that your directory's permissions are what you think they are?

Comment: I'm currently only in a position to test a rather strange situation, but as it can legitimately occur, I'd like to detect it anyway.
I have created a new local folder and have explicitly denied "write" permissions for my user (and also the Administrator user to be sure).

So, unusually, I am the owner of the directory, but cannot write to it. 

This is definitely preventing Ruby from creating and writing a file using `File.open("...", "w+")`, because as soon as I remove the write deny, the file can be created/edited.

Perhaps #attributes only returns "readonly" for files and not directories.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it by using `world_writable?(filename)`

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-world_writable-3F

Comment: This isn't working. It is returning nil in all situations. I have tested it by writing a new file to the directory and reading its contents back again.
`code    directory = "C:" + File::SEPARATOR + "1234"

    puts File.directory?(directory).inspect
    puts File.world_writable?(directory).inspect
    File.open(directory + File::SEPARATOR + "newfile.txt", "w+"){|f| f.write "FileContents"}
    File.open(directory + File::SEPARATOR + "newfile.txt", "r"){|f| puts f.read }`